# Normalize or scale columns on pandas multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, normalize

I have a big dataframe that contains two index's. The first is indexing the date and the second is a label index that occurs every day in no particular order. Each column needs to be normalized or scaled between -1 and 1 on a daily basis. Iv'e attached an image that shows the areas that need to be normalized. So basically i'm needing the data normalized by column and day if that makes sense. Since the data i'm working with is so large iv'e included some sample code that generates a replica for testing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#For repeatability
np.random.seed(0)

#The index's
arrays = [
    np.array([
        "Day1", "Day1", "Day1", "Day1", "Day1", 
        "Day2", "Day2", "Day2", "Day2", "Day2",
        "Day3", "Day3", "Day3", "Day3", "Day3"
    ]),
    np.array([
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
    ])
]

#Create the sample dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15, 4), index=arrays, columns=["100", "200", "300", "400"])

#Output the dataframe
print(df) #End of code

"""
             100       200       300       400
Day1 a  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
     b  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357
     c -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
     d  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
     e  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096
Day2 a -2.552990  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165
     b  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759 -0.187184
     c  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163
     d -0.887786 -1.980796 -0.347912  0.156349
     e  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
Day3 a -1.048553 -1.420018 -1.706270  1.950775
     b -0.509652 -0.438074 -1.252795  0.777490
     c -1.613898 -0.212740 -0.895467  0.386902
     d -0.510805 -1.180632 -0.028182  0.428332
     e  0.066517  0.302472 -0.634322 -0.362741
"""
```

Below is the output from this sample with the fields I need to scale between -1 and 1

[image]

No, the index's are Not labeled.

I'm not very familiar with the pandas groupby but it may be what needs to be used. I'm open to any method or suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make use of `scikit-learn` package in addition to `pandas`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))

# Group by level 0, which is the first index corresponding to 'Dayx'
# After applying the scaling function (which output a Numpy array), convert it to a dataframe

df_scaled = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(x), columns=x.columns, index=x.index).round(5))

print(df_scaled)
```

which gives you:

```
            100      200      300      400
Day1 a  0.89496  0.98495  1.00000  1.00000
     b  1.00000 -1.00000  0.93135 -0.54589
     c -1.00000  1.00000 -1.00000  0.49168
     d -0.12293  0.58365 -0.28161 -0.23246
     e  0.62098  0.11266 -0.59500 -1.00000
Day2 a -1.00000  0.52713  1.00000 -1.00000
     b  1.00000 -0.69484 -0.30804 -0.00925
     c  0.69438  1.00000 -0.13358  1.00000
     d -0.30944 -1.00000 -0.93703  0.60402
     e  0.56893  0.84524 -1.00000 -0.21476
Day3 a -0.32714 -1.00000 -1.00000  1.00000
     b  0.31425  0.14014 -0.45953 -0.01429
     c -1.00000  0.40178 -0.03366 -0.35194
     d  0.31288 -0.72205  1.00000 -0.31613
     e  1.00000  1.00000  0.27758 -1.00000
```

Further, to help you understand `groupby`, it actually splits the data frame according to the group you specified (i.e. in the above example, the group is the first level index, `Dayx`. The first group essentially looks like this:

```
             100       200       300       400
Day1 a  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
     b  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357
     c -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
     d  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
     e  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096
```

and the function `scaler.fit_transform()` is then applied on each of these dataframes (in groups).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, I'll try this when I get back to my computer. I'm just curious why the second index labels changed to numbers. The scaling looks good though

Comment: Yeah, my bad, updated it. As you will be creating a dataframe from array, both the columns and index should be passed `columns = x.columns` and `index=x.index`.

Comment: Ok, everything checked out fine. Marked as answered. Thanks!